# Which indexes should have a table for fast execution of large SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table, which data is quickly circulated. Here is its structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks_pending` (
  `pending_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `added_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `additional` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taken` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taken_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `taken_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pending_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `task_id` (`task_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `added_time` (`added_time`),
  KEY `task_id_2` (`task_id`),
  KEY `taken` (`taken`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY
```

Also I have one big query that pulls the desired data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `task_id` AS tid, `pending_id` as pid, `taken_time`, `taken_by`,  `additional`, 
(
    SELECT COUNT( pending_id ) 
    FROM tasks_pending tp
    WHERE task_id = tid
) AS count, 
(
    SELECT remain
    FROM tasks
    WHERE task_id = tid
) AS rem, 
(
    SELECT type 
    FROM tasks tas
    WHERE task_id = tid
) AS type 
FROM  `tasks_pending` 
WHERE  `taken` =  '0'
HAVING 
(
    count > 9
    OR count = rem
    OR type =  'pack'
)
limit 30
```

All columns in where clauses of subqueries had PRIMARY index, so they must execute fast. 
I can't locate problem, maybe you can me? Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm Russian, so sorry for bad English.

UPD: Structure of `tasks` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `task_id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('video','friend','group','like','pack','other') NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `additional` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remain` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `remain` (`remain`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Put indexes on the columns in the where clause,but you query might be sped up using a JOIN.

Comment: @Mihai, thank you, but in where clause i have only `taken` column, and KEY `taken` is already exists.

Comment: OK,post the schema of the other tables also.

Comment: Your query is terrible - indexes are unlikely to help. Refactor it to eliminate subqueries

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You get a count of all records with the same pending_id, but pending_id is an AUTO_INCREMENT field.  So it will be 1 every time.  So what are you really looking for?

Comment: @Tom, oh, it's a boner. Replace `pending_id = pid` to `task_id = tid` in first subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try simplifying your query by using a `GROUP BY` clause and removing your sub-selects.  This could improve performance.  Try this:

```
SELECT  t.task_id, COUNT(pending_id) count, taken_time, taken_by, type, remain

FROM    tasks_pending tp

        JOIN tasks t ON tp.task_id = t.tid

WHERE   taken = 0

GROUP BY task_id

HAVING  count > 9
        OR count = remain
        OR type =  'pack'

limit 30
```

Comment: This query isn't same as mine: i am counting tasks with specified task_id, not all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Our `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses are identical.

Comment: I am counting the number of tasks for each matching task_id as well as you are doing in yours.  Perhaps you could show a data sample or sqlfiddle where they differ.